# When we create a table how to tall SQLITE to set default value of datetime to `now`?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

We have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
 (encoded_url varchar(65) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, modified DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

We want each time a new record is created to fill its `modified` field with `now` time automatically. Can we tall SQLite that it has to do such thing when we create a table or we should always insert `now`when we fill in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the column specification:

```
sqlite> create table t (a datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, b text);
sqlite> insert into t(b) values ('hello');
sqlite> select * from t;
2011-10-16 17:29:54|hello
sqlite> insert into t(b) values ('hello again');
sqlite> select * from t;
2011-10-16 17:29:54|hello
2011-10-16 17:30:04|hello again
```

There are other date/time options, documented in the [column definition](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#tablecoldef) part of the `create table` syntax docs.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
 (encoded_url varchar(65) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, modified DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')) NOT NULL);

Comment: If you want localtime, use select datetime('now','localtime').If you want UTC the just use datetime('now')